# How to prevent angular-ui-select default from being selected when tabbing over field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-select

When tabbing over our `angular-ui-select` fields, the first value is chosen automatically, even though the user did not intend to select it.

I checked GitHub and see [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/pull/803), which seems to contain a fix, but I don't want to edit the source code if there is a way to do what I need within the supported API.

Please note: We are using `angular-ui-select` version 17.0 in our app.  We had to stop at this version because it was the last version that allowed us to pass in an expression to the `repeat` attribute, rather than a string, which is critical to one of our major components.

Posting here because the CONTRIBUTING.md said to.

Answer (score 1):

This came down to what I consider a bug in ui-select.  If you have ui-select automatically open when the user tabs into the field, the first item is automatically selected for a single-select field.  I created a version of the code that doesn't do this and pushed it to bower.

Check it out here if you need it: https://github.com/granteagon/ui-select-temp

I intend to build a version I can pull request, but there are a few tests that I need to update with the knowledge of not automatically selecting.  Deadlines.

I also would like to refactor my changes to just fix a bug as opposed to using a new attribute, but that's my opinion and I have yet to clear it with the ui-select project team.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove-selected` attribute to the `<ui-select>` tag:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/1672

Comment: That's not what I need and it doesn't work, unfortunately.  The scenario is:

1) There is nothing selected in the select.
2) The user tabs into the field and it pops open automatically.
3) Since it popped open, it for some reason, pre-selects the first item.
4) User tabs away after doing nothing else, and the first item has been selected, which was not intended.